# Pushing unity project to github is hanging

Tags: unity-game-engine, github

I am trying to push a unity project to github. The project is 10GB in size but once gitignore is factored the size is more around 3GB which shouldn't be too big for github. I also have a .gitattributes file for use with git lfs (which I am pretty sure is configured right).

Each time I try to push to github, it hangs like so:
[look at last line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RdIf.png). It will just stay like this forever. Seems like its stuck on something.

I looked up my issue and people have been doing things like changing the post buffer using "git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000" and it seems to work for them, but it never has for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com) !! GitHub (and in general all Git platforms I know) has a maximum file/project size limit! Why? -> because parsing large files for any changes everytime is extremely expensive! Here `Git LFS` is used to only push references to large files into the repository and keep the actual data on a separate data storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my bad on this one. My unity project is simply too big. I've settled for simply including the scripts for now in my GitHub repo as they house the majority of my work that I would be interested in sharing. I have misunderstood the usage of GitHub here, housing entire projects is something more for a site like itch.io as opposed to GitHub, which is more for source code